# Creating a regasm'ed object in javascript

Tags: javascript, dll, com, activex, regasm

For reasons I won't get in to, I have to create an object from a .NET dll in javascript.  The browser I'm using is some ridiculous proprietary thing, but that means it has no security settings, so I'm 100% that's not the issue, before everyone starts chiming in about IE's ActiveX settings.

I found the .dll that held the class I needed, and regasm'ed it.  I tracked down its CLSID in my registry, just to make sure that everything took and that the library names were still the same.

So now I'm calling `new ActiveXObject()` using its `ProgID` in Javascript, and my try-catch is returning "Automation server can't create object."  Any other object I try to make works fine, just not this one.

I've been using this class successfully inside Visual Basic, but the Committee Upstairs has decided that instead of a nicely packaged .EXE, they want a web app that runs inside this browser of theirs (I guess to justify wasting all that money on a license for it).

So, what have I forgotten to do?  What's the correct chain of events that needs to take place to successfully create an object from a .NET dll in JavaScript?

Comment: You have forgotten to post some code

Comment: The code isn't the problem, it's the process.  I've discovered that if I use an <object> tag, I can create the object, but not access any of its methods or properties.  Something about the way I tried to make it COM-accessible; that's all I'm looking for clarification on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you

1. use a reflector (i.e.. ilspy)
      a) given it's not obfuscated
2. decompile the library
3. migrate the methods/functions 
   into a JavaScript library? You might be able to use a tool like JSil to help you convert that code if you are unfamiliar with the library code base.